# Update From Select Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have these tables and i need to do an update from "aeronave" table comparing dates from "detalle_mantenimiento".

http://prntscr.com/cxds08

This is what i tried to do.

`update (
    select matricula, matricula_aeronave, fecha_termino, estado_id_estado
    from aeronave
    inner join aeronave_mantenimiento
    on aeronave_mantenimiento.aeronave_matricula = aeronave.matricula
    inner join mantenimiento
    on mantenimiento.id_mantenimiento = aeronave_mantenimiento.mantenimiento_id_mantenimiento
    inner join detalle_mantenimiento
    on detalle_mantenimiento.mantenimiento_id_mantenimiento = mantenimiento.id_mantenimiento
    WHERE  detalle_mantenimiento.fecha_termino >= SYSDATE)
    set estado_id_estado = 1;`

But the error I had was the following:

> "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
>              map to a non-key-preserved table.

The SELECT it's working, but i can't find what is that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Joins in Oracle can be updated if you meet these conditions - 
1. Only one base table is updated
2. All other tables are key-preserved: each of them must have at most one row for each row of the base table.

In your case it would mean, the keys for the tables aeronave_mantenimiento, mantenimiento or detalle_mantenimiento are not the keys of the join. This link has a simple example to illustrate what a "Key-Preserved Table" is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#i1006318

You might want to rewrite your query, try using subqueries instead of joins. It might help.